# Crontab not executing scripts

Tags: python, macos, cron, cron-task, shebang

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pyautogui
import random

screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()

x = random.randint(0, screen_width)
y = random.randint(0, screen_height)

pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)

print("Success!")
```

Here is the crontab entry:

- - - - - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3 /Users/tylerkivelson/Desktop/python/mouse_move_test.py

I did the ./mouse_move_test.py command in the terminal after using the chmod +x mouse_move_test.py
and got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mouse_move_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

and I think this might be the reason why the crontab won't run the script? I am very lost

Comment: `pyautogui` is a third-party module.  You have to install it yourself.  Did you do that?

Comment: Also, you haven't shown us the crontab entry at all...

Comment: I'm not a macOS user, but normally cron jobs are things that run in the backround, without a GUI. What are you expecting here? That this script will take over your mouse cursor and move it?

Comment: @JohnGordon pyautogui is fully installed and I have double checked the crontab to make sure I have the right path

Comment: How, exactly, did you install the module?  And you still haven't shown the crontab entry.

Comment: @JohnGordon I installed it using pip install pyautogui, I am pretty new to this so I'm sorry if some of these questions seem stupid

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have two versions of Python installed on your system, and `pip` installed the module for a different version than you are using to actually run the script.  Show us the output of this command `pip --version`

Comment: @JohnGordon here is the output: pip 22.3.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

Comment: Show us the output of this command `/usr/bin/python3 --version`

Comment: How do you know that crontab isn't running your script?  What actual output are you expecting to see?

Comment: @JohnGordon the /usr/bin/python3 --version is 3.8.2 and I'm essentially trying to get a webscraper to scrape a certain website at a specific time each day but I can't get that or this mouse_mover script to work with cron. I appreciate all your help with this

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this is a Python version mismatch issue.

When you run your python script with this command:

```
./mouse_move_test.py
```

Your shell opens that file and finds this line at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

So the shell is going to use that python executable to run your code.

However, you installed the pyautogui module for the specific version of python installed at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11`.

So, it's very likely the case that `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11` and `/usr/bin/python3` are different versions of python.

To fix this, remove the `#!/usr/bin/python3` line from the top of your python code.

To test your script, you can use the same command that is in the crontab entry:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3 /Users/tylerkivelson/Desktop/python/mouse_move_test.py
```